# EKS Pod folder contents overwritten after mounting EFS volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

We have created a deployment in the EKS cluster. Underlying pods are supposed to have existing content inside a particular directory which was created through the Dockerfile copy command. But when the pod is created an external EFS volume is mounted on the same directory path due to some application requirements. When we login to the pod and check the contents we found that the existing files have been overwritten by the EFS volume contents. We would like to have both the file contents in place once the EFS volume is mounted on the Pod. Please help us to achieve this.

Comment: You can either (1) stop mounting the PVC to the location in which the files exist or (2) copy the files from the image container into the PVC in an initContainer.

Comment: That seems totally expected – mounting something over an existing directory will always cause the content that was previously there to be hidden.  This is a generic property of Unix mounts but it also applies to Docker and Kubernetes volume mounts.  If the content is in the image and not the EFS volume, what should make it visible in the container filesystem?

Comment: Hey, @masseyb thank you for the suggestion. Could you please share any code snippets of the same?

Comment: Hey, @DavidMaze thanks for the suggestion. But the same does not happen in a docker container running in the local system. The files from the container image as well as from the mounts both are visible that's why we want to achieve the same behaviour from the EKS pods as well. Although its EFS volume not the EBS volume

Comment: There's a feature in Docker that copies image content into volumes.  It only happens on plain Docker and not Kubernetes, and only with Docker's named volumes and not bind mounts, and only the very first time you use the volume (if the image is updated, the volume contains the old content and the image content is hidden).  It sounds like you might be thinking of this feature, but it comes with so maiy caveats that I'd recommend trying to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, docker in kubernetes can be fun, I’d suggest not using the VOLUME directive in any docker image that you’re building to use in kubernetes, you can end up in situations where a docker volume is created on the node where the pod is scheduled and is mounted to the same directory that a pvc is mounted and you’ll realise it too late and have to come up with procedures to migrate the data from docker volumes on a specific host to the shared pvc’s and drop the docker volumes and update the docker builds, and … I digress, just don’t.

Comment: Thanks, guys for your valuable inputs